# 500 Search engine indexes, each need to be computed. how to scale?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, indexing

I am designing a system which has 500 indexes, each of which are a calculation based on tables with millions of rows and I am joining between the tables and doing all sorts of fairly complex logic, so often times a single query take 10 minutes or so. I am currently doing this in mysql and I am not doing anything in parallel. So 10 minutes for the first index calculation, then 10 minutes for the next, and 10 minutes for the 3rd, ... 10 minutes for the 500th ... it takes a long time!

How do people typically build up many indexes which are based on complex calculations of many tables and rows? do they just do them in parallel? Do they throw more hardware at it? Are there best practices out there I could follow?

Comment: Please give us more clues of what you are doing.

Comment: I have hundreds of millions of objects, and each has many attributes. I am doing a bunch of calculations on people depending on the values of each attribute. Sometimes an attribute dictates the algorithm, sometimes it's a combination of attributes together that dictate the algorithm. Either way, currently everything is done in serial, and it's taking a very long time. Since I posted this I tried doing some things in parallel, and with 16 threads on oracle I was able to reduce the time, but it's still very slow. How do people typically make these sorts of calculations faster?

Comment: Which is taking the time?  The fetching of the data or the computation?

Comment: Since it's oracle I am not 100% sure. I am guessing the fetching of the data since it's the joining and scanning which takes so long in the explain plans. the computations are fairly simple: moving data from one table to another with filters, and doing avg, sum, min, max.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem that Google's Big Query was designed to solve.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery

Comment: Maybe I should have said that it needs to be all in house. I do not have permission to distrubte this data to systems outside of my network.

Answer (score 0):

[*Shard-Query*](https://shardquery.com/2014/04/24/shard-query-2-5-is-now-released/) is code to perform MySQL queries in parallel.

Comment: Is it possible to take shard-query and put it into a cluster of mysql servers? Currently with oracle and 16 threads it is still taking over 24 hours. I would like less than an hour. How do people achieve that sort of data computation time?